# Devise Omniauth finds deleted user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, devise, omniauth

I used omniauth after having installed devised for authentication. I installed omniauth-facebook and I was able to successfully have myself sign in with facebook. I deleted the user record from the database and I deleted the permissions I gave the app via facebook's settings.

The problem I am running into is that when I try to go back and sign up for another user account using the same facebook account, the app thinks it is still in the database.

Server logs

```
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."provider" = 'facebook' AND "users"."uid" = '12345'  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  User Exists (0.3ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."email" = 'example@yahoo.com' LIMIT 1
   (0.1ms)  ROLLBACK
```

Code implementation within the user model

```
  def self.from_omniauth(auth)
    where(auth.slice(:provider, :uid)).first_or_create do |user|
      user.provider = auth.provider
      user.uid = auth.uid
      user.full_name = auth.info.name
      user.remote_avatar_url = auth.info.image
      user.email = auth.info.email
    end
  end
```

I have tried to reset the db as well.

Comment: Do you have any User validation(at `first_or_create`) since its `(0.1ms)  ROLLBACK` and from where the `SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."email" = 'example@yahoo.com' LIMIT 1` this query is getting fired?, put some logs on user or inspect user for errors

Comment: Just using the default devise :validatable option within the user model

Comment: did you restart the server?

Comment: I have the same problem and found that when I queried the user with the provider and uid (of the deleted account) I found there was an ActiveRecord::Relation object. Did you solve your problem?